# Does KMM works in Android Studio - Windows Version

Tags: windows, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I need to build an app for both iOS and Android.
I am getting this error after restarting Android Studio.

> Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin issue
> Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin is supposed to work on macOS only

I am using a windows machine.
Please tell me, if there is any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

KMM works in Windows.
There is an **incorrect warning** shown in Android Studio for the plugin stating "KMM Plugin is only available on macOS", which is probably the reason for the confusion.

[image: Plugin Error]

**Note:** Though KMM works in Windows Machine, there are limitations.

- Using a Windows machine, you can **only write Android and shared module code**
  (Java & Kotlin).
- Creating and running iOS simulators are **NOT** possible.

These are **limitations from Apple** rather than from KMM.
They are applicable for most of the cross-platform technologies like KMM, Flutter, etc.

Refer to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43528) thread for more info.

Comment: Correct, trying it here and yes, you can write kotlin native code and use it on Windows or Linux systems, yet this message is misleading and should be changed as it discourages the use of KMM.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that I am not able to create a KMM project on windows. It gives me error : Project wasn't configured
    Command 'pod install' failed.
    Please (re)install CocoaPods and try again. So now how to I create the project. I understand that working on the iOS part wont be feasible but I'm trying to learn KMM and get to know the technology

Comment: on windows you need to install cocopods separately with gem