# Cannot import io.ktor to common module of KMM in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

So I am a newbie to Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile and mobile development in general. I am trying to follow this tutorial here [on KMM tutorials](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/use-ktor-for-networking.html#connect-ktor) to use Ktor in my project.

After adding dependencies, as shown in the build.gradle.kts
below (dependencies for commonMain, androidMain, and iosMain):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }

    val ktorVersion = "1.5.2"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

I tried to `import io.ktor.client.*` to a class in the common module, but it won't resolve. However, when I tried to do the same thing for a class in the Android module then it works. Please see the screenshots below:
[image: import in the Common module]
[image: import in the Android module]

So my question is: Where did I go wrong? Or, is it supposed to be like this? From the documentation, I believe that the networking I am trying to do is supposed to be done in the common module, instead of in the platform specific module.

Please help, I have been looking around to understand what the problem is but no luck. Thank you!

Edit:
I have been having this notification in Android Studio
[image: Issue]

I googled it and it seems that the error notification [is incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677466/does-kmm-works-in-android-studio-windows-version)

Comment: I have the same resolution error in Android Studio 4.1.2, 4.2 beta 6, and Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 although the project compiles without any errors. Most likely this is a bug in the KMM plugin.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman is correct even I have faced this a lot of times and sometime i still face this. Normally i do `gradle` sync again and that works for me but few times I need to do `Invalidate Cache and restart`. Please try adding your code and run if that works then you don't have any issues except from the KMM Plugin itself.

Comment: I've tried sync gradle and invalidate cache + restart Android Studio, but none of them worked. I'm still lost in this issue!

Answer (score 5):

Updating `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` from 1.4.10 to 1.4.31 in root `build.gradle.kts` fixed the issue for me.

This is how my `build.gradle.kts` file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06")
        classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.4.4")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks

Comment: Thank you!!!!! It finally works. How did you figure that the problem is with the kotlin gradle plugin?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me, despite having the same setup.

Comment: no idea how do you get this file. My `build.gradle.kts` looks like this (cause it's cloned from their repo) https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/jvm-js-fullstack/blob/master/build.gradle.kts